# How to center main div horizontally and still have a div on its left

Tags: css, positioning, center, css-position

i'm looking for the best way to do the following:

```
--------------------------|--------------------------
|                                                   |
|    --------  -------------------------            |
|    | menu |  |                       |            |
|    |      |  |                       |            |
|    --------  |       #content        |            |
|              |                       |            |
|              |                       |            |
|              |                       |            |
|              -------------------------            |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
--------------------------|--------------------------
```

The div `#content` is centered horizontally, fixed width. The div `#menu` sticks to the left side of `#content`.

At the moment i have both divs inside a div `#wrap` that has the width of `#content` and `margin:auto`. I position `#menu` absolute and give it a negative `margin-left`. But this way if the browser window get's smaller `#menu` doesn't force a horizontal-scrollbar (which it should for usability reasons).

Thanks for a better solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided all widths are fixed, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/hvrzx/

It requires one additional div, but removes all positioning.
Compute `margin-left` of `#innerwrap` using the following formula: `(o+c)/2-i`, where `o` is the width of `#outerwrap`, `c` is the width of `#content` and `i` is the width of `#innerwrap`.

Change of `#innerwrap`'s width affects the gap between `#menu` and `#content`.

Answer (score 1):

simple use something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    <!-- content -->
    <div id="menu">
    <!-- menu content -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Where "wrapper" will force width of your layout. everything else is the same, except that I prefer left:-200px for example insted of margin-left:-200px; for "menu"...

of course "menu" need to be absolute to "content", etc. "content" is position:relative.

Comment: Doing it your way div .wrap would be centered which means the whole layout is centered, not only div #content?

Comment: you can place "wrapper" where you want, on left, right, center, ... its your choice, if you give as more informations about what are you doing maybe we can help you further, ...

Comment: or you don`t need wrapper and just give padding-left:200px; on content then margin-left:-200px; and then when you put your menu on left:-200px; it will still be inside content, didn't try this, but sounds like it should work, at least in modern broswers.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? in a css sheet

```
#menu {overflow:scroll};
```

Comment: Not really, that would affect the contents of #menu.